# Image appearing before the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When my site is loading up the image always appears straight away (even when it's still loading) however I want it to appear at the exact same times as the text does to make it look like it loading up at the same time. This is the code I have used to make what I see

Javascript

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
     $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
});

$.fn.srcLazy = function (src, callback) {
  let elem = $(this);
  let img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener('load', function () {
      elem.on('load', function () {
         if (callback) callback();
      });
      elem.attr('src', img.src);

  });
  img.src = src;
} 

$('#my-image-in-the-page').srcLazy("./images/ohridimage1.jpg", function () {
    // Show text here!
});

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "flex";
}
```

CSS (LOADING PAGE)

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width:100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #Fff;
  animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
}
.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
}
@keyframes loader {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg);}
  25% { transform: rotate(180deg);}
  50% { transform: rotate(180deg);}
  75% { transform: rotate(360deg);}
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% { height: 0%;}
  25% { height: 0%;}
  50% { height: 100%;}
  75% { height: 100%;}
  100% { height: 0%;}
```

CSS

```
#myDiv {
  margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.image1 {
  position: flex;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  style: float
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  width: 300px;
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<HTML lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="dropdownmenu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="rainbowheading.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="loadingcss.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="image.css">
<script src="loading.js"></script>
<title> North Macedonia </title>
       <script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="rainbow"> The pearl of the Balkans: Macedonia </h1>
  <div class="navbar">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">Macedonian Dispora</a>
  <a href="cities.html">Cities</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">History
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Ancient History</a>
      <a href="#">Ottoman Period</a>
      <a href="#">Yugoslav Period</a>
      <a href="#">Modern History</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</head>




    <script src="loading.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loadingcss.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="loader-wrapper">
      <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
    </div>

  <div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom"></div>
    <div>
      <h2>Welcome to my website about my country Macedonia (Makedonija)</h2>
      <p>Macedonia officially the Republic of North Macedonia, is a country in the Balkan Peninsula in Southeast Europe. It gained its independence in 1991 as one of the successor states of Yugoslavia. A landlocked country, North Macedonia has borders with Kosovo to the northwest, Serbia to the northeast, Bulgaria to the east, Greece to the south, and Albania to the west. It constitutes approximately the northern third of the larger geographical region of Macedonia. The capital and largest city, Skopje, is home to roughly a quarter of the country's 2.06 million inhabitants. <br>
        The majority of the residents are ethnic Macedonians, a South Slavic people. Albanians form a significant minority at around 25%, followed by Turks, Romani, Serbs, Bosniaks, and Aromanians.</p>
    </div>
      <img class="image1" src="./images/ohridimage1.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to load an image in the background and show it when finished with another elements like text you need to load the image in the Image Object like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // Here you can set the url that was loaded in the background here
    // to an actual `<img>` element. Browser uses cache now to load the image quickly.
});
img.src = 'image url here';
```

As soon as you set the src the image will get loaded but nobody can see it. This will force the browser to load image in the background and cache it. So now when you set that exact src to the img element the browser will use cache to show the image so the image will be loaded quickly with whatever you want to show.

`UPDATE` --------

You can do it in a better way in jquery:
Let's say you have bunch of images. Then instead of setting their `src` set their `data-src` attribute and then use this functionality to do something when all images loaded:
This is the HTML:

```
<img class="my-images" data-src="<image url 1>" />
<img class="my-images" data-src="<image url 2>" />
<img class="my-images" data-src="<image url 3>" />
<img class="my-images" data-src="<image url 4>" />
```

This is the JS:

```
$.fn.whenImagesLoaded = function (callback) {
    let found = $(this);
    let counter = found.length;
    found.each(function (i, item) {
        let elem = $(item);
        let img = new Image();
        img.addEventListener('load', function () {
            elem.on('load', function () {
               counter--;
               if (counter === 0 && callback) callback();
            });
            elem.attr('src', img.src);

        });
        img.src = elem.attr('data-src');
    });
}
```

So now you should not set src on the image at first but you have to do this:

```
$('.my-images').whenImagesLoaded(function () {
    // Hide loading text here and show images! 
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sabox/7nxj26dL/)

Comment: Thanks that makes sense

Comment: :) Updated my text to convey the message a little better.

Comment: Do i put that in the HTML? file? and what do I write to make it work?

Comment: So it depends if you want to use this functionality a lot in the project I suggest to do it in an javascript file like a library. So let me to do it in another way. Are you using JQuery?

Comment: Saw your code again apparently you are using jQuery. So I will update the code above.

Comment: Yea I am I'm just not sure how to put it because I'm a beginner at JQuery

Comment: I updated my code on the javascrript section what else do I need to do? For it to be able to work?

Comment: So do not change your question. Then someone else when starts to read this question gets confused.

Comment: I added the code and it's not working or maybe I entered it wrong

Comment: I have updated my code a bit after you have copied. Could you check it again. If didn't work lets create a jsfiddle for it. I will show you how. Just comment here if didn't work.

Comment: But first create the jsfiddle so we are on the same page as to what is the code and what you want to achieve.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pq75enmd/9/ This is what I want to do I want the image and text basically to appear at the same time I think I might have placed the code in the wrong area

Comment: Your code structure on `<head>` and `<body>` is wrong. Please see the JS Fiddle I put forward in my response above at the end of the answer.